# How to add an app to my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

Ok this is might be the dumbest question ever.. but i cannot for the life of me figure out how to add one of my Facebook apps to one of my Facebook pages. When I would look at my app settings on developers.facebook.com there used to be a link to view the App Profile Page. Then from there I could click an Add to Page link. But I have no clue how to do this now grrr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Frederick Behrends" />

    <title>Facebook PageTab Dialog Generator</title>
</head>

<body>

AppID:<input type="text" id="AppID" value=""/><br />
<input type="button" value="Add to page" onclick="AddToPage();"/>

<script>
function AddToPage(){
    var Next,AppID;
    AppID = document.getElementById('AppID').value;

    if(isNaN(AppID) === true){
        alert('AppID ungültig');
        return false;
    }


    if(Next == '' || typeof Next == 'undefined')
        Next = 'http://www.facebook.com/';

    window.open("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id="+AppID+"&next="+Next,"PageTab","width=800,height=500");

    return false;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Use this html file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

I think it´s good to specify that the Next parameter it's the Facebook Canvas App URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=__APP_ID__&pages
```

where **__APP_ID__** is the application ID of the application you wish to add. Pretty simple.