# How to add my canvas app on my facebook page's tab

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-canvas

I have created a test app on Facebook. I need to add that on my Facebook page tab like this:

https://www.facebook.com/PumpkinMasters/app_1478139035806591

**I have added the platform `Page Tab` in my app**.

And then I've tried following steps:

- Go to my page
- Click on **More**, then **Manage Tabs**
- Click on **Add or Remove Tabs** link

Here I did not find the name of my app, there are only two apps **Events** and **Notes**.

My app is looking like this:

https://apps.facebook.com/1619017204982756/

Can some one please tell me how can I add a tab on my page with my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know is this a right way to do this but I it has worked for me.

[How to add an app to my Facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794009/how-to-add-an-app-to-my-facebook-page)

Comment: Thanks!   I think it´s good to specify that the Next parameter it's the Facebook Canvas App URL